# Adding a logo in title of Tkinter window

Tags: tkinter

How to add an image(/logo) in the title of the Tkinter window? I know how to set a text as Tkinter window title, but how to add an image in the title?

Comment: You mean replace the feather icon? Use the root.iconphoto() method.

Comment: @Novel Thanks, that worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the icon with iconphoto() method.
I use PIL for loading icons.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
root = Tk()
path = "your icon path"
load = Image.open(path)
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
root.iconphoto(False, render)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to: [this link](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/python-3-and-gui-tkinter-logo-insertion)

use "wm_iconbitmap()"

example:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.wm_iconbitmap('myicon.ico')
root.wm_title('Title')
root.mainloop()
```

Or use "iconbitmap()"